# How to get the MD5 hash of a string directly in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, md5sum

How do I get the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash of a string directly from the terminal?

For example, I want the string `abcdefg` hashed. Currently the [md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) command only accepts a filename as input. I want to simply enter the following line and everything be done with.

```
md5sum abcdefg
output: ac54bcf346e578feb46888b3ecd2344f
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `md5 -s abcdefg`

Comment: TA=$(echo 40483760ff0a3649  | tr '.' ' ');for c in $TESTDATA; do echo $c | xxd -r; done

Answer (score 372, accepted):

You can also say something like this :

```
~$ echo -n Welcome | md5sum
83218ac34c1834c26781fe4bde918ee4  -
```

It basically does the same thing as described by @enzotib, but is perhaps a bit simpler.

Comment: why are there spaces and a dash at the end?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is because the MD5sum was applied to a stream of data, as opposed to reading a file content, which has a name associated to it.

Comment: Notice that the `-n` is mandatory. Without it, your hash will be totally wrong since it includes the newline character.

Comment: This helped me on macOS too, though it's slightly different: `echo -n Welcome | md5`

Comment: How could I ignore `-` at the end. @jfmessier

Comment: @alper `echo -n Welcome | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'` will take the first "column" separated by spaces. You could also use `cut` as well.

Comment: On Mac OS, instead of `md5sum`, write `md5`.

Comment: What's unusual is that stdin vs args has a slightly different behavior. As an arg, it will check if the file exists. For stdin it does not.

Answer (score 85):

Very simple, it accepts stdin, so

```
md5sum <<<"my string"
```

To avoid the trailing newline added by the shell:

```
printf '%s' "my string" | md5sum
```

Comment: Giving both @messier and @enzotib a vote; both fall in my prized "elegant simplicity" category. I'd be apt to use the `<<<"` pipe in a script; `echo string` wins for the commandline. Well done.

Comment: +1 for using `printf` correctly. If you want to have the sum without the `-`, put `| cut -d ' ' -f 1`. Example usage: `sum=$(printf '%s' 'some string' | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`

Comment: it's weird but the `<<<` operator and the `printf` function are giving completely different results for md5 hash! the result of printf is correct though!

Comment: it seems using the `<<<` operator sends a newline to the md5sum!

Comment: Yes, it does, as I said between first and second example

Comment: I got wrong result with the first  command `b9bfa87a6a126911f2246c7a615bff27  -` instead of `2ba81a47c5512d9e23c435c1f29373cb  -`

Answer (score 45):

```
$ echo -n 123456 | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

you can create a shell script.

For example,the script name is md5.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo   -n   $1 | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

permission execute:

```
 chmod +x md5.sh
```

Then:

```
$ md5.sh 123456
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

If your system is macOS. You need to modify this script:

```
$ echo -n 123456 | md5 | awk '{print $1}' 
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

Comment: alternative to awk: `cut -d ' ' -f 1`

Comment: I created a function `md5() { echo -n $1 | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'; }` in .bashrc and then I can use `$ md5 test` in the command line. thanks for the answer

Comment: Shorter `awk` command: `'$0=$1'`

Answer (score 15):

```
openssl md5 filename
openssl sha1 filename
```

For string pipe the content using echo

```
echo -n 123456 | openssl md5
```

Answer (score 11):

Running md5sum with no arguments at all will cause it to read input from the terminal.  Type or paste whatever you want, and when you are done, press `ctrl-d` to end the input.

Comment: yeah, you're right too. but `ctrl+d` needs to be pressed twice for it to work.

Comment: @James, if it does not follow a newline, yes.  If you hit it after hitting enter, it only needs once.  When it does not follow a newline, it just forces all of the characters typed on the line so far to be processed immediately instead of waiting for a newline.

Answer (score 9):

My quick poke at the `--help` for `md5sum` demonstrates that the command:

```
md5sum -
```

will then give a prompt for simple input. Inputting some text and then using <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to signify end of file then causes `md5sum` to spit out the MD5 of the raw text you entered (including that <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it's a CR, IIRC).

Less to type and no piping! And avoiding your plaintext password being recorded in shell history! Woo!

If you do not want that trailing CR (which is usually the case if you want to hash a password), don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are many examples to do this, but some of them are not equivalent because some of them explicitly or implicitly include the newline, and some others do not.

**I would like to clearly specify which of the popular methods includes the newline and which are not.**

**Here are some examples along to calculating the *md5* hash WITHOUT trailing newline (CORRECT):**

Using a file with text:

```
$ echo -n "test" > test.txt
$ wc test.txt
0 1 4 test.txt
$ md5sum test.txt
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  test.txt
```

**Note:** `-n` in `echo` means: "do not output the trailing newline".

Using `echo` with `-n` inline:

```
$ echo -n "test" | md5sum
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
```

Using `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s" "test" | md5sum
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
```

Using only `md5sum` command:

(Let's write `md5sum`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then write string `test` and then press double combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>)

```
$ md5sum
test098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
```

Using `md5sum -` command:

(Let's write `md5sum -`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then write string `test` and then press double combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>)

```
$ md5sum -
test098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
```

**Here are some examples along to calculating the *md5* hash WITH trailing newline (SO NOT CORRECT):**

Using a file with text:

```
$ echo "test" > test_n.txt
$ wc test_n.txt
1 1 5 test_n.txt
$ md5sum test_n.txt
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  test_n.txt
```

Using `echo` WITHOUT `-n` inline:

```
echo "test" | md5sum
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

Using [here strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html):

```
$ md5sum <<< "test"
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

Using only `md5sum` command but with <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after writing the text:

(Let's write `md5sum`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then write string `test` and then press agaien <kbd>Enter</kbd> and once combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>)

```
$ md5sum
test
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

Using `md5sum -` command but with <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after writing the text:

(Let's write `md5sum -`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then write string `test` and then press agaien <kbd>Enter</kbd> and once combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>)

```
$ md5sum -
test
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

Answer (score 2):

In my scripts I found that there are 2 things that you should know about this issue.

- It does not matter if you do `echo "$myvariable"` or `echo -n "$myvariable"`
  but you should always use the doubleqoutes for strings and always use the same method. if not things won't match.
- in the output you get always a trailing space and a dash as shown in the example:

  ```
  $ echo -n Welcome | md5sum
  7803ffcaea43bb81a439fde13b29bc35  -
  ```

to get rid of that and stay only with the code `7803ffcaea43bb81a439fde13b29bc35`, 
do: `echo "$myvariable" | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1`

Comment: Don't forget the `-n` parameter here to avoid outputting the trailing newline, which would lead to a wrong md5: `echo -n $myvariable | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1`

Answer (score 2):

For my case the best solution to hash a plain string is:

```
md5hash=$(echo -n "myhashedstring" | md5sum | head -c 32)
```

will result in `2e8f8b94e488a2f442a55951862612aa`