# How do I calculate md5sum for a variable?

Tags: command-line, md5sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the MD5 hash of a string directly in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53846/how-to-get-the-md5-hash-of-a-string-directly-in-the-terminal)

I have a given variable and I have to calculate its md5sum. I have tried with "md5sum $variable", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

md5sum takes filenames as parameters.

Iif you have a string you want to calculate the hash of, you need to pass it to md5sum's standard input via a pipe:

```
echo -n $variable | md5sum
```

(-n to suppress adding a newline)

Comment: not *-e*, but **-n**

Comment: Also, you need to quote `"$variable"`, otherwise leading and trailing spaces are not taken into account, as multiple consecutive spaces inside the content of variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

```
echo -n "$VARIABLE" | md5sum
```

As suggested in comments, `echo -n` should will not add a new line. Also, using quotes will keep new lines as in original content.

Comment: echo will append a trailing newline then, use `echo -n $VAR` instead.